# How to find 48 working hours date excluding saturday,sundays and holidays in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, date-arithmetic

There is a requirement to find the 48th and 24th working hour for  some module.

**Requirement:**

For suppose if I pass `2nd May` as a parameter to the function, the output should be `27th April` for `48 hours` and `28th APRIL` for `24 hours` (as 1st May is holiday and 29th and 30th April fall under Saturday and Sunday)

The problem is with two successive holidays. For example,  to create a `dummy` data we insert 2nd May as a holiday and run the code on `3rd May` that should retrieve `27th April` for `48 hours` and `28th APRIL` for `24 hours`.

But my function doesn't seem to be working for successive holidays. Somewhere the counter increment seems to be in the wrong location.

***Considerations:***
**Weekend** : Saturday and Sunday
**Days that need to be excluded**: Saturdays,  Sundays and Holidays in the given holiday calendar:

**Holiday table creation:**

```
CREATE TABLE HOLIDAY_TAB
(
   HOL_DATE      DATE,
   DESCRIPTION   VARCHAR2 (100) DEFAULT NULL
);
insert into  HOLIDAY_TAB values (TO_DATE ('26-Jan-2017', 'DD-MON-YYYY'),NULL);
insert into  HOLIDAY_TAB values (TO_DATE ('29-Mar-2017', 'DD-MON-YYYY'),NULL);
insert into  HOLIDAY_TAB values (TO_DATE ('14-Apr-2017', 'DD-MON-YYYY'),NULL);
insert into  HOLIDAY_TAB values (TO_DATE ('01-May-2017', 'DD-MON-YYYY'),NULL);
insert into  HOLIDAY_TAB values (TO_DATE ('02-Jun-2017', 'DD-MON-YYYY'),NULL);
insert into  HOLIDAY_TAB values (TO_DATE ('26-Jun-2017', 'DD-MON-YYYY'),NULL);
insert into  HOLIDAY_TAB values (TO_DATE ('15-Aug-2017', 'DD-MON-YYYY'),NULL);
insert into  HOLIDAY_TAB values (TO_DATE ('25-Aug-2017', 'DD-MON-YYYY'),NULL);
insert into  HOLIDAY_TAB values (TO_DATE ('28-Sep-2017', 'DD-MON-YYYY'),NULL);
insert into  HOLIDAY_TAB values (TO_DATE ('02-Oct-2017', 'DD-MON-YYYY'),NULL);
insert into  HOLIDAY_TAB values (TO_DATE ('19-Oct-2017', 'DD-MON-YYYY'),NULL);
insert into  HOLIDAY_TAB values (TO_DATE ('25-Dec-2017', 'DD-MON-YYYY'),NULL);

commit;
```

Function to written to capture holiday :

**Function:**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION CSE.F_HOL_CHECK_ABC (i_hol_date DATE)
   RETURN DATE
AS
   valid_working_day   DATE := i_hol_date;

   day_C               holiday_nvs%ROWTYPE;

   CURSOR c_hol
   IS
      SELECT *
        FROM HOLIDAY_TAB
       WHERE TRUNC (hol_date) = TRUNC (i_hol_date);

   CURSOR c_hol_24
   IS
      SELECT *
        FROM HOLIDAY_TAB
       WHERE TRUNC (hol_date) = TRUNC (i_hol_date + 3);

   CURSOR c_hol_48
   IS
      SELECT *
        FROM HOLIDAY_NVS
       WHERE TRUNC (hol_date) = TRUNC (i_hol_date + 2);
BEGIN
--   FOR rec24 IN c_hol_24
--   LOOP
--      IF (rec24.hol_date IS NOT NULL)
--      THEN
--         valid_working_day := i_hol_date - 1;
--      END IF;
--   END LOOP;

   OPEN c_hol;

   FETCH c_hol INTO day_C;

   IF c_hol%FOUND
   THEN
      SELECT DECODE (TO_CHAR (i_hol_date - 1, 'D'),
                     1, i_hol_date - 3,
                     i_hol_date -  )
        INTO valid_working_day
        FROM DUAL;
   END IF;

   CLOSE c_hol;


   RETURN (valid_working_day);
END;
/
```

Not sure if the function is right. But there is a weird situation that my query doesn't give same result when tried using the SYSDATE compared to date literal.

**Run 1 with date manually:**

```
SELECT TRUNC (
          DECODE (
             TO_CHAR (TO_DATE ('03-MAY-2017', 'DD-MON-YYYY'), 'D'),
             2, F_HOL_CHECK_ABC (TO_DATE ('03-MAY-2017', 'DD-MON-YYYY') - 4),
             DECODE (
                TO_CHAR (TO_DATE ('03-MAY-2017', 'DD-MON-YYYY'), 'D'),
                3, F_HOL_CHECK_ABC (TO_DATE ('03-MAY-2017', 'DD-MON-YYYY') - 4),
                F_HOL_CHECK_ABC (TO_DATE ('03-MAY-2017', 'DD-MON-YYYY') - 2))))
          AS "48HOURS",
       TRUNC (
          DECODE (
             TO_CHAR (TO_DATE ('03-MAY-2017', 'DD-MON-YYYY'), 'D'),
             2, F_HOL_CHECK_ABC (TO_DATE ('03-MAY-2017', 'DD-MON-YYYY') - 3),
             F_HOL_CHECK_ABC (TO_DATE ('03-MAY-2017', 'DD-MON-YYYY') - 1)))
          AS "24HOURS"
  FROM DUAL;
```

**Run 2 with sysdate:**

```
SELECT TRUNC (
          DECODE (
             TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'D'),
             2, F_HOL_CHECK_ABC (SYSDATE - 4),
             DECODE (TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'D'),
                     3, F_HOL_CHECK_ABC (SYSDATE - 4),
                     F_HOL_CHECK_ABC (SYSDATE -2))))      as "48 hour"                          ,

                                                     TRUNC (
                                                        DECODE (
                                                           TO_CHAR (SYSDATE,
                                                                    'D'),
                                                           2, F_HOL_CHECK_ABC (
                                                                 SYSDATE - 3),
                                                           F_HOL_CHECK_ABC (
                                                              SYSDATE -1))) as "24 hour" from dual;
```

Any help in this is really appreciated. All I need is to skip the holidays, Sundays and Saturdays i.e; non working hours and give me 48 working hour day and 24 hour working hour day

Here is another attempt with code 2 using counters:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION CSE.F_HOL_CHECK_S_NS (i_hol_date    DATE,
                                                 i_S_NS        NUMBER)
   RETURN DATE
AS
   valid_working_day   DATE := i_hol_date;
   counter             NUMBER := 0;
   day_number          NUMBER := 0;
   hol_count           NUMBER := 0;
   day_C               holiday_nvs%ROWTYPE;

   CURSOR c_hol (hol_date_c DATE)
   IS
      SELECT *
        FROM HOLIDAY_TAB
       WHERE TRUNC (hol_date) = TRUNC (TO_DATE (hol_date_c, 'DD-MON-YYYY'));
BEGIN
   IF i_S_NS = 0
   THEN
      LOOP
         IF c_hol%ISOPEN
         THEN
            CLOSE c_hol;
         END IF;

         OPEN c_hol (valid_working_day);


         IF c_hol%FOUND
         THEN
            valid_working_day := valid_working_day - 1;

            SELECT TO_CHAR (TO_DATE (valid_working_day, 'DD-MON-YYYY'), 'D')
              INTO day_number
              FROM DUAL;

            SELECT COUNT (*)
              INTO hol_count
              FROM HOLIDAY_TAB
             WHERE TRUNC (hol_date) =
                      TRUNC (TO_DATE (valid_working_day, 'DD-MON-YYYY'));

            --valid_working_day:=valid_working_day-1;

            --            SELECT DECODE (TO_CHAR (valid_working_day - 1, 'D'),
            --                           1, valid_working_day - 3,
            --                           valid_working_day - 1)
            --              INTO valid_working_day

            --               FROM DUAL;


            IF (hol_count > 0)
            THEN
               valid_working_day := valid_working_day - 1;
            --  counter := counter + 1;
            ELSIF (day_number = 1 OR day_number = 7)
            THEN
               valid_working_day := valid_working_day - 1;
            END IF;
         ELSIF (   TO_CHAR (TO_DATE (valid_working_day, 'DD-MON-YYYY'), 'D') =
                      1
                OR TO_CHAR (TO_DATE (valid_working_day, 'DD-MON-YYYY'), 'D') =
                      7)
         THEN
            valid_working_day := valid_working_day - 1;
         ELSE
            counter := counter + 1;
            valid_working_day := valid_working_day - 1;
         END IF;

         EXIT WHEN counter >= 3;
      END LOOP;
   --elsif (i_S_NS <> 0) then
   --null;
   END IF;
--valid_working_day := valid_working_day - 1;

   RETURN (valid_working_day);
END;
```

Comment: Try it with `TRUNC(SYSDATE)`. SYSDATE includes the time, which TRUNC removes.

Comment: @BobJarvis we tried it...that didnt work either.there is an observation that i made just now..as the code started working for sysdate ..its subtracting hours and it started working at 3:00 AM here...Would you be able to help me in tweaking my code 2 please?

Comment: Having trouble following the wall of code - can you provide a [MCVE] with a few dates and your expected output (and an English explanation of why that output is expected).

Comment: I don't see the problem statement. (Don't expect us, or at least me, to read your code and to try to guess from the code what problem it is supposed to solve!) I have seen a similar problem, where the input is a date-time like May 2, 2017, 10:30 AM, and the question is to find the date-time that is 24 work hours (or 48 or any other number) from the input, counting only work hours: for example from 8 AM to 5:30 PM on work days only (excluding weekends and holidays). That problem makes perfect sense, and I may find the solution I wrote for it. Please advise. (Also: what is weekend? Sat-Sun?)

Comment: @MT0 I've added simple example on what is expected and what is not working in the above edit.Could you please help me in this ?

Comment: @mathguy The code is provided just for ease of understanding.Sorry for giving the entire data in single page.However i am looking for 2 working days back date and yes weekend i referred is Saturday and Sunday.If you can help me with the code that you had worked on we can see if that works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a pure SQL answer. The trick is to generate a series of prior dates which covers all eventualities. In countries that I'm aware of, there are no more than two public holidays in a row (Christmas and Easter in the UK, Hogmanay in Scotland). Allowing for the weekend too that means there can be up to four days to be excluded from consideration.

As commenters have pointed out, in other countries there may longer runs of public holidays, so you may need to adjust the offset accordingly.

Anyway, with two days to target we need a range going back six days (plus one for luck). This will gives us a result set of the seven days preceding the target date and the :

```
select (tgt_date - 7) + (level-1)
from dual
connect by level <= 7
```

Now we're set. We can use a trick with the `'IW'` date mask to determine the day of the week as a number and rule out Saturdays and Sundays in a culturally neutral fashion. We can left join to `holiday_tab` to rule out public holidays. Then we rank what's left and select the most recent two dates:

```
SQL> with hdr as (
  2               select dr.dt
  3                      ,  case
  4                            when (1 + dt - trunc(dr.dt, 'IW') in (6,7) then 1
  5                            when h.hol_date is not null then 1
  6                            else 0
  7                         end as hol
  8              from ( select trunc(date '2017-05-02' - 7) + (level-1) as dt
  9                     from dual
 10                     connect by level <= 7
 11                   ) dr
 12            left join holiday_tab h
 13            on h.hol_date = dr.dt
 14              )
 15     , rhdr as (
 16         select hdr.dt
 17                    , row_number() over (order by hdr.dt desc) rn
 18             from hdr
 19             where hdr.hol = 0
 20             )
 21  select rhdr.dt
 22         , decode( rhdr.rn, 1, '24hr', '48hr') as cat
 23         , to_char(rhdr.dt, 'DY') as dy
 24  from rhdr
 25  where rn <= 2;

DT        CAT  DY
--------- ---- ------------
28-APR-17 24hr FRI
27-APR-17 48hr THU

SQL>
```

Given yesterday 02-MAY-2017 as the target date this skips Monday (Mayday holiday) and the weekend to identify the two previous working days.

---

If you need a function you could do something like this:

```
create or replace type dt_nt as table of date;

create or replace function prior_working_days
    ( p_target_date in date
      , p_no_of_days in number := 2)
    return dt_nt
is
    return_value dt_nt;
    offset pls_integer := (p_no_of_days+4+1);
begin
    with hdr as (
                select dr.dt
                        ,  case 
                               when to_char(1 + dt - trunc(dr.dt, 'IW') in (6,7) then 1 
                               when h.hol_date is not null then 1
                               else 0
                            end as hol
                from ( select (trunc(p_target_date) - offset) + (level-1) as dt
                         from dual
                         connect by level <= offset
                        ) dr
                     left join holiday_tab h
                     on h.hol_date = dr.dt
                )
        , rhdr as (
            select hdr.dt
                   , row_number() over (order by hdr.dt desc) rn
            from hdr
            where hdr.hol = 0
            )
    select rhdr.dt 
           bulk collect into return_value
    from rhdr   
    where rn <= p_no_of_days;
    return return_value;
end prior_working_days;
/
```

This returns a SQL table of dates:

```
SQL> select * from table( prior_working_days(sysdate));

COLUMN_VA
---------
02-MAY-17
28-APR-17

SQL>
```

Comment: Consider "Ascension of Jesus" (which is always on Thursday, 39 day after Easter) and "Pentecost Monday" (50 day after Easter) - they may appear in a row with Labor Day (1st of May). In worst case (i.e. earliest possible date) Easter happens on 22nd of March, which let to free Ascension Day (30th of April), Labor Day (1st of May), Saturday, Sunday.

Comment: `TO_CHAR( dr.dt, 'DY' )` will not return `SAT` or `SUN` when the `NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE` is not an English speaking language.

Comment: Some organisations may give [privilege days](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privilege_day) as holidays and if this involves Maundy Thursday followed by the Easter Friday and Easter Monday public holidays then there can be 3 holiday days in a row (around a weekend).

Comment: @MT0 - when I was in the British Civil Service we got a half-day for Maundy Thursday. Not sure how half-days would fit into the OP's model.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it all in SQL:

```
WITH dates ( dt, lvl ) AS (
  SELECT CAST( TRUNC( :your_date ) AS DATE ), 0 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
  SELECT CAST( dt - INTERVAL '1' DAY AS DATE ),
         CASE
           WHEN ( dt - INTERVAL '1' DAY ) - TRUNC( dt - INTERVAL '1' DAY, 'IW' ) >= 5
           OR   hol_date IS NOT NULL
           THEN lvl
           ELSE lvl + 1
         END
  FROM   dates d
         LEFT OUTER JOIN
         holidays h
         ON ( d.dt - INTERVAL '1' DAY = h.hol_date )
  WHERE  lvl < 2
)
SELECT *
FROM   dates
PIVOT  ( MAX( dt ) FOR lvl IN ( 1 AS DATE24, 2 AS DATE48 ) );
```

*(Note: using `CAST` should not be necessary but without I get `ORA-01790: expression must have same datatype as corresponding expression`)*

Or, as a function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION F_HOL_CHECK_S_NS (
  i_hol_date DATE,
  i_S_NS     NUMBER
) RETURN DATE
AS
  p_date DATE;
BEGIN
  WITH dates ( dt, lvl ) AS (
    SELECT CAST( TRUNC( i_hol_date ) AS DATE ), 0 FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
    SELECT CAST( dt - INTERVAL '1' DAY AS DATE ),
           CASE
             WHEN ( dt - INTERVAL '1' DAY ) - TRUNC( dt - INTERVAL '1' DAY, 'IW' ) >= 5
             OR   hol_date IS NOT NULL
             THEN lvl
             ELSE lvl + 1
           END
    FROM   dates d
           LEFT OUTER JOIN
           holidays h
           ON ( d.dt - INTERVAL '1' DAY = h.hol_date )
    WHERE  lvl < i_s_ns
  )
  SELECT dt
  INTO   p_date
  FROM   dates
  WHERE  lvl = i_s_ns;

  RETURN p_date;
END;
/
```

Comment: The `ORA-01790` error is a bug in 11gR2. The bug affects recursive WITH clauses which use DATE parameters.  `cast()` is not necessary in 12c.

Comment: The recursive WITH clause is highly neat in the way it avoids the need for an offset. Definitely the tidiest solution for 11gR2 or higher

Answer (score 1):

My proposal would be a function like this one:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION F_HOL_CHECK_S_NS (i_hol_date DATE, i_S_NS NUMBER) RETURN DATE AS
    TYPE DATE_TABLE_TYPE is TABLE OF DATE;
    Holidays DATE_TABLE_TYPE;

    the_date DATE := i_hol_date;
    duration INTEGER := 0;
BEGIN

    ID i_hol_date IS NULL OR i_S_NS IS NULL THEN
        -- Avoid infinite loop
        RETURN NULL;
    END IF;

    -- Just for performance reason
    SELECT HOL_DATE
    BULK COLLECT INTO Holidays
    FROM HOLIDAY_TAB
    WHERE HOL_DATE < i_hol_date;

    LOOP
        the_date := the_date - 1;
        IF TO_CHAR(the_date, 'fmDy', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = american') NOT IN ('Sat', 'Sun') AND TRUNC(the_date) NOT MEMBER OF Holidays THEN
            duration := duration + 24;
        END IF;
        EXIT WHEN duration >= i_S_NS;
    END LOOP;
    RETURN the_date;
END;    


SELECT F_HOL_CHECK_S_NS(DATE '2017-05-02', 24) FROM dual;
SELECT F_HOL_CHECK_S_NS(DATE '2017-05-02', 48) FROM dual;
SELECT F_HOL_CHECK_S_NS(SYSDATE, 24) FROM dual;
SELECT F_HOL_CHECK_S_NS(SYSDATE, 48) FROM dual;
```

Comment: You can add `WHERE HOL_DATE < i_hol_date` to the `BULK COLLECT` query.

Comment: @MT0, yes indeed